# Javascript executing onload "GET" method multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very odd problem where a javascript function runs multiple times on page load (7 times for Chrome, 3 times for IE, 7 times for Firefox, 6 times for Opera, 4 times for Safari and 4 times for Edge). What the???

Also the xmlHttp.send(null) returns a network error but the function still executes (allbeit 3-9 times).

Also also, the alert function only runs once!

Any ideas?

```
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Silverlight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var webServiceUrl = location.protocol + "//" + location.host +
"/WebService/WebService.svc/JSON/";
    var browserInfo = navigator.userAgent;
    var webMethod = "OpenConnection?BrowserInfo=" + browserInfo.replace(" ", "%20");
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    alert(webServiceUrl + webMethod);
    xmlHttp.open("GET", webServiceUrl + webMethod, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height: 100%">
```

Comment: just a question, since you are including `jquery` why are you using `XMLHttpRequest` instead of `jQuery.ajax()`?

Comment: The crazy thing is I've tried that too with the very same result.


    jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
            url: webServiceUrl + webMethod, // Location of the service
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', // content type sent to server
            dataType: "json", //Expected data format from server
        });

Comment: Ok this is getting weird up in the house. It works fine if I create a new js file and put the function in it, then call it from the Default.aspx page in the usual way:

    
    <script>
        openConnection();
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the script inside the jQuery's `ready()` method, so it executes after page loads, not during.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var webServiceUrl = 
    ...
});
```

Comment: This works, but then, today, all my old code now works too when only yesterday it didn't. I've either got ghosts in my garage or bats in my belfry.

Thanks for the ideas guys..